# Incorporate external files into R package on install

Tags: r, package, ggmap

I have a charts package which is using ggmap and ggplot2 to produce region-specific charts for our reporting toolset.

For ggmap we are using a Google map for each of 15 different regions. Each map is around 10MB in size, so there is 150MB of data. We run the reports maybe a couple of hundred times to get different analyses and for different sites within that geographical area - so I don't want to fetch the map for every single report if I could help it.

I'd like to set it up so that the maps are cached either when the package is installed, or perhaps more practically the first time that region's chart is run and a copy of the map doesn't exist already.

I'm aware of using the inst/extdata for putting external files into your package - but not of a way to install things into your package once the package has been downloaded / installed.

Is there a suitable way to do this?

Comment: add the code in `.onAttach` and `.onLoad`?

Comment: But where would you save to? If I was building a package, I'd use inst/extdata. What do you do if the package is already installed?

Comment: sorry misunderstood your qn. perhaps you can save on the fly `if (!file.exists(system.file('inst/exdata/map01.Rdata'), package="mychartPackage")) { #plot and save into that file path }`

Comment: So once the package is installed is the file path for extra files still inst/extdata?

Comment: You can choose to put it somewhere else provided you have admin rights to the folder

Comment: Thankyou - I'll try that!